# configuring security for Classic asp site running on Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: iis

I Moved a classic asp site over from Windows Server2003 to Windows Server 2012. Under the IIS Authentication Just to prove the site comes up I enabled Anonymous Authentication, all was working. Now I've disabled this and only have Windows Authentication enabled. The Application pool that I've set the site against has `.NET CLR Version set to v2.0` `enable 32-bit set to true` Ive also set the Identity to use **NetworkService** and the Managed Pipeline set to classic.

From within IIS on the WWWRoot properties Security tab, I have ensured NetworkService and my Domain User group have relevant permissions and I've also done the same on the physical path of the site. I've recycled the app pool and restarted my site, but whenever I try to browse to the site, it asks for my user password. Even after entering my password It still comes back with a 401.1 - unauthorized error. So I added the same roles to the asp.net authorization rules in IIS but this didn't make any difference (didn't expect it too really since this isn't a .net app). Any ideas where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue by design. It is a loopback issue. To resolve the problem in IIS create a new binding with the actual IP Address of the website and leave the hostname blank. It's because everything is on a single server, browse on a different server and the problem doesn't exist